# how to set background color of image in Android

Tags: android, background-color, transparent

I have png image which have some transparent area in between image. I am trying to set color programmatically to that area but its not working.

This is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_cat_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/del"
    card_view:civ_border_color="@color/tabsScrollColor" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

in xml i have custom attribute

```
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

using this card_view in xml i am able to set color but i need to change programmatically its color.is there anyway i can set this property programatically? Please anyone help me out.[image: how to fill color]

Comment: check object of `CircularImageView` it has function to set color.

Comment: i try but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CircularImageView` is a custom view. You can change it's properties as shown below.

```
 CircularImageView circularImageView = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_cat_icon);
    // Set Border
    circularImageView.setBorderColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor));
    circularImageView.setBorderWidth(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CircularImageView imageView = (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_cat_icon);

Drawable color = new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);

LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{color, image});
imageView.setImageDrawable(ld);
```